# How to forward declare structs in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

I want to doubly link a parent to a child struct. This I know works in C++.

```
struct child;

struct parent{
   child* c;
} ;

struct child{
   parent* p;
} ;
```

, but in C with typedefs I can't make it work without warnings.

```
struct child;

typedef struct {
    struct child* c;
} parent;

typedef struct {
    parent* p;
} child;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    parent p;
    child c;
    p.c = &c;
    c.p = &p;
    return 0;
}
```

gives me `warning: assignment to ‘struct child *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘child *’`. Is the first child struct then overwritten, or are there two distinct data structures now `struct child` and `child`?

Is this even possible in C? My second thought would be using a `void*` and cast it to child everywhere, but either option leaves a sour taste in my mouth so far.

Comment: Try `typedef struct child { ... } child;`. Otherwise the compiler can't connect the two.

Comment: strange: new versions of gcc accept your code without any warning.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There is a rather strong warning [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7cqsqY).

Comment: A bit of free advice: don't use typedef for structs in C. C does not have classes, give up trying to make things look like classes, just use the struct keyword everywhere explicitly. Typedef just hides important information. Typedef of a pointer to struct is even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different structures. The first one is

```
struct child;
```

and the second one is an unnamed structure with the alias name child

```
typedef struct {
    parent* p;
} child;
```

You need to write

```
typedef struct child {
    parent* p;
} child;
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey Initially in the question it is supposed that the structure child will have the alias name child.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the structs then typedef them later:

```c
struct child {
    struct parent* p;
};

struct parent {
    struct child* c;
};

typedef struct parent parent;
typedef struct child child;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    parent p;
    child c;
    p.c = &c;
    c.p = &p;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare structures like this:

```
typedef struct parent {
    struct child* c;
}parent;

typedef struct child {
    parent* p;
}child;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     parent p;
     child c;
     p.c = &c;
     c.p = &p;
     return 0;
}
```